# F-measure and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, precision-recall, information-retrieval

I would compare two classifiers (A and B), where B is obtained from A.

I would exploit the **F-measure** computed on two samples (of two independent populations, p1 and p2, respectively):

> A -> F-measure1 on *p1*
>
> B -> F-measure2 on *p2*

Once obtained an F-measure index for the first and the second classifier, I might execute an hypothesis testing in order to measure if index of second classifier (F-measure2) is greater or smaller and such difference is statistically significant.

Does it make sense?
Can I use the typical hypothesis testing for average of a population, substituting average with F-measure?